# Authentication using oauth2

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, passwords, registration

I am trying to create web-forum with user authentication, using Github and Google. I've already managed to get user information with access token, like login, email and etc. But I don't get the workflow for authenticating this user in my database.

In order for user to register, he need to provide email, login and password. All the examples and tutorials I saw, was stopping at the sessions and that's it.

My website has database with posts and comments, and to fetch, for example, user's created posts, I need to get the user id, then I will lookup in the database. I thought, maybe, I can use access token as a password, since it's unique, but it always changes and has an expiration date. Then I thought, to left the password input empty and register user without it, but I think, that's not very secure. How should I do it?